# Python using "IN" in a "IF ELSE" loop

Tags: python, loops, operators

i have a list of tuples that i loop through in a simple for loop to identify tuples that contain some conditions.

```
    mytuplist = 
    [(1, 'ABC', 'Today is a great day'), (2, 'ABC', 'The sky is blue'), 
     (3, 'DEF', 'The sea is green'), (4, 'ABC', 'There are clouds in the sky')]
```

I want it to be efficient and readable like this:

```
    for tup in mytuplist:
        if tup[1] =='ABC' and tup[2] in ('Today is','The sky'):
            print tup
```

The above code does not work and nothing gets printed.

This code below works but is very wordy. How do i make it like the above?

```
for tup in mytuplist:
    if tup[1] =='ABC' and 'Today is' in tup[2] or 'The sky' in tup[2]:
        print tup
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
mytuplist = [
    (1, 'ABC', 'Today is a great day'),
    (2, 'ABC', 'The sky is blue'),
    (3, 'DEF', 'The sea is green'),
    (4, 'ABC', 'There are clouds in the sky')
]

keywords = ['Today is', 'The sky']
for item in mytuplist:
    if item[1] == 'ABC' and any(keyword in item[2] for keyword in keywords):
        print(item)
```

Prints:

```
(1, 'ABC', 'Today is a great day')
(2, 'ABC', 'The sky is blue')
```

Comment: imo this is the best way

Comment: How do we do the opposite, example,  `if item[1] != 'ABC' and any(keyword in item[2] for keyword in keywords):` to get tuple 3 and 4?

Comment: @jxn well, this would give you the tuple 3:  `if item[1] != 'ABC' and all(keyword not in item[2] for keyword in keywords):`. Basically, we are asking for all keywords not to match.

Answer (score 3):

You don't, because `in` with a sequence only matches the whole element.

```
if tup[1] =='ABC' and any(el in tup[2] for el in ('Today is', 'The sky')):
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach (which, however, needs to be parenthesized as `x and (y or z)` to be correct) is necessary `tup[2]` *contains* one of your key phrases, rather than being an element of your set of key phrases. You could use regular-expression matching at the cost of some performance:

```
if tup[1] == 'ABC' and re.match('Today is|The sky', tup[2])
```